trying to import a single part with 101 different configurations into an assembly
I'm trying to import a single file with 101 different configurations into an assembly. I'm trying to go the macro route. I'm not very familiar with VBa, especially not Solidworks VBA api.
I'm using Co-pilot for assistance and it keeps calling the part congifuration .GetConfigurationNames function and that fails completly.


     Set swPart = swModel
     
     Set swConfigMgr = swPart.ConfigurationManager
     
     ' Log configurations in the part
     logFile.WriteLine "Configurations in part document:"
     partConfigNames = swConfigMgr.GetConfigurationNames
     For i = LBound(partConfigNames) To UBound(partConfigNames)
         logFile.WriteLine partConfigNames(i)
     Next i

Does the API only work for assemblies and not for part configurations? What am I don't wrong?
The error is:
Run-time error '438'

Object doesn't support this property or method


"congifuration"?
